# Uploading Arduino Code to ESP32 Dev Module

Tags: tensorflow, arduino, esp32

*I'm trying to recognize humans using the ESP32 Cam and Arduino Uno, when uploading I'm getting this error. Any help?*
**Arduino Settings:**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQZg8.png
**Error:**
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.
**Code:**

```
 * Run person detection on ESP32 camera
 *  - Requires tflm_esp32 library
 *  - Requires EloquentEsp32Cam library
 *
 * Detections takes about 4-5 seconds per frame
 */
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <tflm_esp32.h>
#include <eloquent_tinyml.h>
#include <eloquent_tinyml/zoo/person_detection.h>
#include <eloquent_esp32cam.h>

using eloq::camera;
using eloq::tinyml::zoo::personDetection;


void setup() {
    delay(3000);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("__PERSON DETECTION__");

    // camera settings
    // replace with your own model!
    camera.pinout.freenove_s3();
    camera.brownout.disable();
    // only works on 96x96 (yolo) grayscale images
    camera.resolution.yolo();
    camera.pixformat.gray();

    // init camera
    while (!camera.begin().isOk())
        Serial.println(camera.exception.toString());

    // init tf model
    while (!personDetection.begin().isOk())
        Serial.println(personDetection.exception.toString());

    Serial.println("Camera OK");
    Serial.println("Point the camera to yourself");
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("Loop");

    // capture picture
    if (!camera.capture().isOk()) {
        Serial.println(camera.exception.toString());
        return;
    }

    // run person detection
    if (!personDetection.run(camera).isOk()) {
        Serial.println(personDetection.exception.toString());
        return;
    }

    // a person has been detected!
    if (personDetection) {
        Serial.print("Person detected in ");
        Serial.print(personDetection.tf.benchmark.millis());
        Serial.println("ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: you tried to upload to arduino uno?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded to Arduino Uno

Comment: Same error when I upload to the Arduino Uno board

Comment: well arduino uno only has 32K of memory while ESP32 has 4M of Memory, the arduino's memory is insufficient, try upload it directly to the esp32 cam

Comment: by the way, what do you need arduino uno for, it would be helpful if you can describe what are you trying to achieve and how you plan to achieve it

Comment: Would it work with the arduino uno r3?

Comment: I'm trying to process the feed of the camera, detect humans, then use motors on a car to move the car closer to the detected human. I have the car part ready, just need to fix the detection.

Comment: Did you check the specs?  An Arduino Uno R3 has 2K of RAM.  It can't even hold an image, much less process it.  The processor runs at 16MHz, approximately 200 times slower than your desktop.  It's just not designed for general computing.

Comment: We won't be processing it on the Arduino itself. The video feed will be processed on my PC and motor movements will be sent back to the Arduino using the HC-05 Bluetooth module.